# Objective-C initiate/restore wifi connection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, network-programming

I am currently developing an app - a packet sniffer. It has a server and a client component. Server is written using java. And the client is written using objective-c. I have a centralized server. App is installed in the clients. It will run in frequent intervals and sends information to server. Everything works fine except the following part :

I am using `airport en1 sniff` command to sniff packets. When it is sniffing the packets, it goes to monitor mode and I lose the internet connection. Are there any frameworks or API that would allow me restore my previous internet connection or initiate a new internet connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A wireless interface in "sniff mode" can't be used to participate in network traffic. It's a special mode that has it busy listening to everybody else. It can't be used for both simultaneously.

Comment: You're right that it can't be simultaneous. I wanna restore back my previous connection after sniffing is complete i.e., I'll stop sniff mode and go back to participate in network traffic? All I want is toggle between the modes i.e., sniff mode - participate in network - sniff mode - participate in network and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various functions in the [System Configuration framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html) to do this.

Comment: Actually not. It's a known limitation of wireless cards in sniff mode. The card's enabled, it's just unable to participate in traffic while it's trying to listen to everybody else.

Comment: I know that. However, you should be able to switch to a different network configuration that "resets" the network interface. I haven't tried it myself but the SC framework is the only way to do this sort of stuff.

Comment: Sorry - I suppose I misunderstood the OP's requirement. Sounded like he wanted both.